# Singular value decomposition of a matrix and eigendecomposition of the product of this matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, svd

Consider $X$ a $n\times d$ real matrix. By the Singular value decomposition we have that

$X = USV^{t}$ where $V$ is an orthogonal matrix of size $d\times d$, $S$ the matrix containing the singular values of size $n\times d$ and $U$ a matrix with orthonormal column of size $n\times n$. My aim is to prove that the eigenvalues of $X^{t}X$ are proportional to the square singular values of $X$. For this, I need to consider an eigendecomposition of $X^{t}X$ wich is possible since this matrix is symmetric. We have  $X^{T}X = (USV^{t})^{t}(USV^{t})=VS^{t}SV^{t}$, and we know that $S^{t}S$ is a diagonal matrix and that $V^{t}=V^{-1}$.

Now if I consider an eigendecomposition of $X^{t}X$ given by $PDP^{-1}$, we have the equality
$VS^{t}SV^{-1} = PDP^{-1} $.

But I don't see how I can continue, nothing is telling me that $V=P$ at my knowledge ?

Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: I thought the singular values of $X$ were the *square roots* of the eigenvalues of $X^\top X$?

Comment: You are totally right sorry. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this hint helps with your next step.

From $ VS^tSV^{−1}=PDP^{−1}$, we could move the P matrices over to get $ P^{-1}VS^tSV^{−1}P=D$. As $S^tS$ is diagonal and $(P^{-1}V)^{-1} = V^{-1}P$, does this tell us anything about the relationship between the eigenvalues of $D$ and $S^tS$?

Similarly, what can find out about the eigenvalues of $S^tS$, if we move the $V$ matrices over to get $ S^tS=V^{−1}PDP^{−1}V$?

Comment: Thank you a lot Patrick for your time.  We have $(P^{-1}V)(S^{t}S)(P^{-1}V)^{-1}=D$ which corresponds to the an eigendecomposition of $D$ so $D$ has the same eigenvalues than $S^{t}S$ ? And since $P^{-1}V=(V^{-1}P)^{-1}$ we can do the same for $S^{t}S$ , I suspect also a relation between the eigenvectors : they are the inverse of each others ?

Comment: Yes. $D$ and $S^tS$ have the same eigenvalues. In general, similar matrices have the same eigenvalues (but they usually do not have the same eigenvectors). What do you mean by the inverse of an eigenvector?

Comment: Great thank you a lot Patrick. We have $(P^{-1}V)$ the matrix of eigenvector of $D$ and $(P^{-1}V)^{-1}$ the matrix of eigenvector of $(S^{t}S$. My previous comment is false : they are not the inverse, I don't know how caracterize this relationship ? I would like to say that they are the same but I'm not sure of this ?